# fixing errors in the style of the site

Tags: css

When I added the google Adsense on my site the content of the site shifted down

How can I make the content beside the google Adsense not under it.

Here is my site: http://saledirection.com/

```
.wrapper {
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you ... can you help me to add a banner ads on the left of the site ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your adsense code with the one below. You need to add `position:absolute;` to the style, which will place the vertical ads next to your main content.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js "></script>
<!-- lkl -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:900px;position:absolute;"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5991916567520964"
     data-ad-slot="4537317534"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: you are so smart thank you very much
can you help me to add a banner ads on the left of the site?

Comment: Not an issue. Sure. Just change the style to `position:absolute;left:0;` that should position an ad to the left side.

Comment: can  you help me also to make the left and right ads fixed

Comment: when i scroll the ads is fixed